# How Can I retrieve logged in user details in router [Laravel 5]?

Tags: php, laravel, router

I have created my router block like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'access.routeNeedsPermission:view-backend'], function() {
        Route::group(['namespace' => 'Hospital'], function () {
            Route::resource('hospital','HospitalController', 
              ['except' => app('\App\Http\Controllers\Backend\Access\Hospital\HospitalController')->allowed_actions()]);

            Route::post('hospital/locations', 'HospitalController@locations');

        });

}

);
```

And I am writing the method like this

```
public function allowed_actions(){

    $page_access = Pageaccess::where('page_id','hospital-management')->firstOrFail();
    $roles = unserialize($page_access->role_id);
    $views = unserialize($page_access->view);
    $read  = unserialize($page_access->read);
    $write = unserialize($page_access->write);

    $common_variable = Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->id : 0;


    $actions = ['create'];

    return $actions;

    exit;
}
```

But the `Auth::check()` returns 0 and I cannot access anything in `Auth::user()`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Routing happens before everything else, your user will be available after the middlewares ran.

Comment: Try modifying your middleware. `[ 'middleware' => ['auth', 'access.routeNeedsPermission:view-backend' ] ]` Are you sure user is authenticated?

Comment: Thanks DigitLimit, I did it in the middleware. Middleware contains the User Auth values.

Comment: tkausl, thanks for bringing it up, it helped.